# Duplicated template files

Tags: joomla-3.x, templates, multilingual, helix3

I duplicated the template to make the website multilingual, and I need to edit the new language template's files but I can't find them on the server! where can I find them?

Comment: Also you can check this useful guide: https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Setup_a_Multilingual_Site

Answer (score 2):

all the language files of the frontend side template is located in the language folder.

for example if you have protostar template :

> en-GB.tpl_protostar.ini
>
> en-GB.tpl_protostar.sys.ini

then these two you can find in the **root/language** folder.

If you have duplicated the template folder, please also make a copy of these two files in the same language folder.

Hope it will help.